# Criteria Query For Getting User With Roles From Many to Many User-Role Relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, many-to-many, hibernate-criteria, criteria-api

```
public class User {

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "t_user_roles",
                        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
                        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
    private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();

}
```

```
public class Role {

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(length = 20)
    private RoleType roleName;

}
```

```
public enum RoleType {

    ROLE_CUSTOMER("Customer"),
    ROLE_MANAGER("Manager"),
    ROLE_ADMIN("Administrator");

    private String name;

    private RoleType(String name) {
        this.name=name;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
}
```

```
public PageImpl<UserDTO> getAllUserPage(String query,RoleType role,Pageable pageable) {
            CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
            CriteriaQuery<User> criteriaQuery = cb.createQuery(User.class);
            Root<User> root = criteriaQuery.from(User.class);

            List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
            Predicate finalPredicate = null;

            if (query != null && !query.isEmpty()) {
                String likeSearchText = "%" + query.toLowerCase(Locale.US) + "%";
                Predicate searchByUserFirstName = cb.like(cb.lower(root.get("firstName")), likeSearchText);
                Predicate searchByUserLastName = cb.like(cb.lower(root.get("lastName")), likeSearchText);
                Predicate searchByUserEmail = cb.like(cb.lower(root.get("email")), likeSearchText);
                predicates.add(cb.or(searchByUserFirstName,searchByUserLastName,searchByUserEmail));
            }
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            if (role != null){
                Join<User, Role> joinRoles = root.join("roles");
                predicates.add(cb.equal(joinRoles.get("roleName"), role));
                System.err.println(role);
            }
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

            finalPredicate = cb.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0]));

            criteriaQuery.orderBy(pageable.getSort().stream()
                    .map(order -> {
                        if (order.isAscending()) {
                            return cb.asc(root.get(order.getProperty()));
                        } else {
                            return cb.desc(root.get(order.getProperty()));
                        }
                    })
                    .collect(Collectors.toList()));

            criteriaQuery.where(finalPredicate);

            TypedQuery<User> typedQuery = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery);
            typedQuery.setFirstResult((int)pageable.getOffset());
            typedQuery.setMaxResults(pageable.getPageSize());

            CriteriaQuery<Long> countQuery = cb.createQuery(Long.class);
            countQuery.select(cb.count(countQuery.from(User.class)));
            countQuery.where(finalPredicate);
            Long totalRecords = entityManager.createQuery(countQuery).getSingleResult();

            List<UserDTO> userDTOList = userMapper.map(typedQuery.getResultList());

            return new PageImpl<>(userDTOList, pageable, totalRecords);
    }
```

Hello friends,

As you can see above, I have been trying to write a Criteria API query that works in all possible scenarios. In this query, the search part works completely dynamically and brings results in all possible cases. If I don't send any data, it brings all Users. However, I am having trouble with the code block I added to perform the search according to the role. I included all the code here because I thought there might be a problem with other queries. As you can see, I have User and Role classes. I cropped only the necessary parts related to the role to keep it short. In a many-to-many relationship, I have searched the internet for how to get users according to their roles, but to no avail. The roles are kept as ENUM in the Role class. There is no problem with the value, but when I execute the query, I get the error `"org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Invalid path: 'generatedAlias1.roleName' [select count(generatedAlias0) from com.gpm.domains.User as generatedAlias0 where generatedAlias1.roleName=:param0]"`. Although the field name is correct, I cannot get any result in any way. Can you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by adding aliases to the "root" and "joinRoles" parts. I did not face this problem in my other queries, but when you have a Many-to-Many relationship and need to join in the query, Hibernate gets confused with aliases. I saw the problem while debugging by evaluating it.

```
root.alias("generatedAlias0"); 
joinRoles.alias("generatedAlias1");
```